# How to split a continuous variable into intervals of equal length (defined number) and list the interval with cut points only in R?

Tags: r, intervals

I would like to divide a set of data into four equal size interval, e.g.:

```
x=c(0:10)

G1: [0,2.5)

G2: [2.5,5)

G3: [5,7.5)

G4: [7.5,10]
```

Is there anyway I can split the data into intervals of equal length (say four in this case) and get the below list including the min and max values:

```
0   2.5   5   7.5   10
```

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the great catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `cut`

```
cut(1:10, c(1, seq(2.5, 10, by=2.5)), include.lowest = T)
#  [1] [1,2.5]  [1,2.5]  (2.5,5]  (2.5,5]  (2.5,5]  (5,7.5]  (5,7.5]  (7.5,10]
#  [9] (7.5,10] (7.5,10]
# Levels: [1,2.5] (2.5,5] (5,7.5] (7.5,10]
```

If you just want the evenly spaced breaks, use `seq`

```
x <- 0:10
seq(min(x), max(x), len=5)
# [1]  0.0  2.5  5.0  7.5 10.0
```

Comment: I would like to split data into same interval size with defined number of intervals, but not by the difference of value. I have edited my question so it'd be clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(x, breaks=cut(x,breaks = 5, labels=c("1","2.5","5","7.5","10")) )
```

does the work? 
(The trick is in the cut function of course)